# How to identify ruby and gemset combination for rvm wrapper

Tags: rvm, wrapper, ruby-1.9.3, gemset

I am trying to install seeing_is_believing in order to display results of every line of Ruby code for ST2.

I am supposed to create a rvm wrapper to generate a ruby binary that can be used by ST2.

I need to decide which ruby and gemset combination I wish to use.

I am currently using ruby version 1.9.3-p429.

In my .rvm directory I have a "gems" and "gemsets" folder

```
gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/INDIVIDUAL GEMS
gemsets/jruby/global.gems
gemsets/ruby/1.8.5/global.gems
gemsets/CONTAINS default.gems, global.gems
```

I am not sure how to select a gemset, if I do not have a gemsets folder within gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429 directory.

I have tried the following.

```
Mikes-MacBook-Pro:Packages mwsage$ rvm wrapper 1.9.3-p429@global.gemset
Gemset 'global.gemset' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-1.9.3-p429 do rvm gemset create global.gemset' first, or append '--create'.
Could not load ruby 1.9.3-p429@global.gemset.

Mikes-MacBook-Pro:Packages mwsage$ rvm wrapper 1.9.3-p429@1.8.5 Sublime Text 2
Gemset '1.8.5' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-1.9.3-p429 do rvm gemset create 1.8.5' first, or append '--create'.
Could not load ruby 1.9.3-p429@1.8.5.
```

The example I have looked at uses rbx@rails3 as their ruby/gemset combo and enter

```
rvm wrapper rbx@rails3 textmate
```

as the instruction is a wrapper for textmate and not ST2.

I couldn't figure out how to identify my interpreter, as he is using rbx, I'd guess mine to be MRI?

The general instructions for install also suggest RBENV. Is this a substitute for rvm?

Also - What is a ruby binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select an existing gemset with `rvm gemset use gemset_name_here` or you can create a new gemset with `rvm gemset create gemset_name_here`.

You might find the following blog post useful for RVM basics. http://strandcode.com/2013/07/11/ruby-version-manager-rvm-overview-for-rails-newbs/

RBENV is an alternative to RVM. They both perform similar functions.

So in your case, I think you'll want `rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.3-p429@gemset_name_here sublime`

In the context of the instructions at https://rvm.io/integration/textmate, I think "binary" is effectively a simple script providing instructions on which ruby version and gemset to use.